# Missing AllDifferent constraint in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, solver

I am trying to use the solver in Excel 2007 but I did not find "alldifferent" constraint in it, e.g:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwLkP.png)

I can see "integer" "binary" but there is no "alldifferent".

Can someone help me find it? Thanks!

Comment: 1) upgrade to Excel 2010 or higher, or 2) add multiple constraints similar to ABS(v1-v2)>=1.

Answer (score 1):

The alldifferent constraint was added in Excel 2010.

You can impose alldifferent constraints by using additional formulae and constraints in Excel 2007. Below is a simplified example ...

A screenshot of the setup ...

[image]

Here, Eqn1 is `=A2*10+A3*9+A4*8+A5*7+A6*6` and Eqn2 is `=A6*10+A5*9+A4*8+A3*7+A2*6`

You can see that Cell B2 contains the CSE equation `{=MIN(ABS(A2-A3:$A$6))}`. This is dragged down to B5, where the equation is `{=MIN(ABS(A5-A6:$A$6))}`.

As an example, Solver is setup with:

- SetObjective: $F$2
- To: Min
- By Changing: $A$2:$A$6
- Subject to the constraints:

  - $A$2:$A$6 <= $D$2:$D$6
  - $A$2:$A$6 >= $C$2:$C$6
  - $B$2:$B$5 >= $E$2:$E$5
  - $A$2:$A$6 = integer
- Select a Solving Method: Evolutionary

Below is a screenshot ...

[image]

Below is a screenshot of the solution.

[image]

It found the expected answer of 1,2,3,4,5.

Changing SetObjective to $G$2 gets the answer 5,4,3,2,1.